# Why does my OpenVPN connection drop after ~40s?

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I'm testing an OpenVPN Connection between the following devices:

Server (Amazon Linux 2)

```
Linux xxxxx 4.14.146-120.181.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 18 17:01:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [Fedora EPEL patched] [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.06
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=yes enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no
```

Client (Yocto Linux)

```
Linux xxxxx 4.4.185-cip35 #1 PREEMPT Wed Oct 30 15:03:38 UTC 2019 i586 i586 i386 GNU/Linux

OpenVPN 2.4.6 i586-poky-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 30 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019, LZO 2.10
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=no enable_plugin_auth_pam=no enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=no enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=no enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=no with_aix_soname=aix with_broken_putenv=no with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_libtool_sysroot=/home/xxxxx/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-nlp-32-poky-linux/openvpn/2.4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot with_mem_check=no
```

I've generated Keys & Certificates using the Easy-RSA script and distributed these between the server and client. Server and Client have a tap0 virtual network adaptor created, and I've manually assigned the servers tap adaptor an IP address of 192.168.20.1/24 and the client 192.168.20.2/24. Nether server or client have another network adaptor on the same subnet.

I have the following configuration files:

Server:

```
proto tcp
port 1194

dev tap0

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem

server-bridge

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120

verb 5
```

Client:

```
port 1194

ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key

client

remote-cert-tls server

auth-nocache
reneg-sec 0

dev tap0

keepalive 10 120

verb 5
```

I can fire up the server, and the client connects. I can then ping, or establish an SSH connection to the server from the client using the IP 192.168.20.1 after initially connecting.

However, after almost exactly 40 seconds, I stop getting a response to my ping. I can see on the server that it is no longer receiving data (verb 5 shows when a packet is read / written). I can see the client is still 'writing' data - in line with the ping command - too.

Eventually, OpenVPN sees a timeout and reconnects - giving me another 40 seconds of communication.

I've tried reducing MTU settings; I've tried turning off authentication and encryption. I've tried with both TCP and UDP connections.

I've tested the exact configuration file, with the same cert and keys on a Debian 9 machine and do not have the same issue. So this is almost certainly an issue with the Yocto Linux client.

Comment: Did you check what happens on the wire by running `tcpdump` on the client side? The point of interest is to check whether the UDP packets are still coming out (around that 40s barrier) and back. This might sched some light on the issue.

Comment: If it is ANYTHING like my ISP, then it is because you are sitting behind Carrier Grade Nat. The CGN cuts off the TCP connection if you don't have short keepalive timer. Mine is as low as 10-15 seconds. Anything higher cuts the connection.

Comment: @kostix Great Suggestion. I see a lot of TCP re-transmissions from the server to the client when the problem occurs, and nothing being sent from the client.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard The connection works from a VM on my workstation (which uses the same router as the client) using exactly the same config, so I don't think it's an ISP issue.

Comment: I would then proceed at collecting the output of `# /sbin/sysctl -a | grep ^net. | sort` on both hosts and then analyzing what `diff -u host1 host2` would show.